# How to identify if a Type is a custom struct?

Tags: .net, reflection, struct, types

For a `Type`, there is a property `IsClass`, but how to know a `Type` is a struct?

Sorry, I have to add some more information.

1. I am using C#.
2. Although `IsValueType` is a necessary condition, **it is obviously not enough. For an Integer is a value type also.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decide a Type is a custom struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296288/how-to-decide-a-type-is-a-custom-struct)

Answer (score 10):

```
t.IsValueType && !t.IsPrimitive && !t.IsEnum;
```

Comment: I dont' get the reason of `!t.IsPrimitive`. `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Char`, `Double` (etc...) are not structs?

Comment: Sometimes in C# we count them as such, because they're value types, but `struct` comes from "structured", referring to structs' composite nature (normally having more than one field, though 0 or 1 is permissable) and the origin of the keyword back in C, though C# and C structs are different in several ways. It's clear from the question that the OP was thinking the latter way rather than the former. This view doesn't take a "turtles all the way down" perspective, but takes the units that can't be broken down any further, to not be structs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about c#, you can use the `IsValueType` property.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a value type (e.g., a `struct`), use **[`Type.IsValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IsValueType`.

Answer (score 0):

Well then, I guess for your requirement then this comes close:

```
bool isStruct = myType.IsValueType && !myType.IsPrimitive;
```

but still `DateTime` isn't covered by that for example. Maybe you would have to add further types you want to exlude manually.

Comment: DateTime gives the correct result of true with this code. It's enums that it doesn't handle correctly.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
 x.GetType().IsValueType();
```

From help:

Type::IsValueType Property
Gets a value indicating whether the Type is a value type.
Value types are types that are represented as sequences of bits; value types are not classes or interfaces. Value types are referred to as "structs" in some programming languages. Enums are a special case of value types.

Comment: Types have different meanings when applied to storage location than when applied to heap objects. Under the hood, every value type has an associated heap type.  Casting a value type to `Object` or to an interface that it implements will create a new heap object whose fields are copied from the value-type instance being cast. Calling `GetType` on a value type will cast it to `Object` first, since value types don't have the type-destrictor field required by `GetType`.