# How to decide a Type is a custom struct?

Tags: c#, struct

For a `Type`, there is a property `IsClass` in C#, but how to decide a `Type` is a struct?

Although `IsValueType` is a necessary condition, it is obviously not enough. For an `int` is a value type also.

Someone suggests the following code:

```
bool IsStruct = type.IsValueType && !type.IsEnum && !type.IsPrimitive;
```

But I am not sure whether it is an accurate method. The formula should tell the difference between struct and other types such as `DateTime`, `int` and `array`s.

As some friends have pointed out that here, I mean **user defined struct and not predefined types**, such as `DateTime`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. A DateTime **is** a struct. Why would you return false there?

Comment: Actually int is a struct type as well. The language specification states "C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types".

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you care. What are you doing? There might be a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Why do I need this function? I am using reflection to show data. When I meet a user struct, I will show its fields.

Answer (score 10):

Technically, an int is also a struct. IsPrimitive just checks if the type is one of the primitive types the CLR handles a little differently. You should be fine with the suggestion `IsValueType && !IsEnum && !IsPrimitive`.

If you want only custom structs (i.e. those not supplied by the BCL), you may have luck excluding types with a FullName that starts with `"System."`, or only including the ones you're interested in by filtering by assembly or namespace, or use a custom attribute.

Comment: +1 Or `"Microsoft."` or `"FSharp."` or . . .  I think he'll have a hard time eliminating them all.

Answer (score 2):

Should be at least

```
bool isStruct = type.IsValueType && !type.IsEnum &&
               !type.IsPrimitive && type != typeof(decimal);
```

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx says:
IsValueType is true if Type is in {bool, byte, char, decimal, double, enum, float, int, long, sbyte, short, struct, uint, ulong, ushort}.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx says:
IsPrimitive is true if Type is in {Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single}.

Than for IsStruct you can use method like this:

```
public static bool IsStruct(this Type type)
{
    return type.IsValueType 
            && !type.IsPrimitive 
            && !type.IsEnum 
            && type != typeof(decimal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a tough time with this. The base Framework doesn't know what all the predefined types in other parts of the Framework are. It's unreasonable to expect the core Framework to know about `System.Drawing.Point`, for example.

OregonGhost has probably the best [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2296312/56778): get the type info and check the `FullName` property to see if it starts with `"System."`. But you'll also need to check for `"Microsoft."` and `"FSharp"`, and possibly others. Just click on "Add a reference" in Visual Studio, and see what names come up.

And then you might risk blocking too much. Microsoft distributes some assemblies via NuGet packages, and the types in those assemblies often have names that start with `"System."` or `"Microsoft."` Do you consider those "Built in" types even though they're not distributed with the Framework?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me
!x.PropertyType.IsSecurityTransparent && x.PropertyType.IsClass

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but you can always consider narrowing the search by known types within the assemblies you wish to search:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(tyepof(OneOfMyTypes))
    .GetExportedTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsValueType);
```

The helps eliminate false positives (safer?), but it's less portable.