# Is class or struct

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

How do I check is the  type class or struct?

```
 protected   T GetNullValue<T>(IDataReader reader, int ordinalId)
    {
        if (reader.IsDBNull(ordinalId))
        {
            //if T is struct.....
            //else if I is class
        }
        return (T)reader.GetValue(ordinalId);
    }
```

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713900/how-to-determine-if-a-net-type-is-a-custom-struct

Comment: @Aim - I'm not so sure of that. The accepted answer is particularly bad in my opinion.

Comment: it is bad form to tack on another question on your existing question like that. It makes the existing answers invalid and the whole post confusing for people later on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (default(T) is ValueType)
   ...
```

is the most efficient thing I can come up with at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Get the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) class for the object, and check it.

```
Type t = reader.GetValue(ordinalId).GetType();
if (t.IsValueType){
    //Struct
} else { 
    //Class
}
```

I suspect you will be using the Type object later on in your code, if you're trying to dynamically handle the results.

Comment: That code won't compile. You can't use `typeof` with an object instance, you have to use `GetType()`

Answer (score 2):

If T is a value type, it cannot be null. To make a value type nullable, you have to use the 
[System.Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) struct.